# How to remove keys and values of JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, key

I'm using Spring Framework and angular JS in Javascript.
and AJAX request succeeded. 
but I had a problem what removing some keys and values.
my code is

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',       
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data:  JSON.stringify(search),
    contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    url: '/yboard/select',
    error: function() {         
        alert("Loading failed!");
    },
    success: function(returnJSON) {     

        if (returnJSON.success) {           

            var result = JSON.stringify(returnJSON.items);
            console.log("no : " + result);      


        } else {
            alert("it's failed");                           
        }
    }
});
```

output is

```
no :     [{"boardID":"9b5199799c908e48051e2e131f2d35cc","no":204,"capital_stock":"","pno_stock":"3204000336","pname_stock":"HEATER","storage_code_stock":"C03","storage_name_stock":"A","price_indicator_stock":"M","unit_stock":"EA","stock_amount_stock":"12.00","tracking_no_stock":"015","standard_stock":"WATLOW: SFRE","client_code_stock":"1193","client_name_stock":"aaa","priority_stock":0},{"boardID":"6a11d21aa400ff6c94d7d7a21b762433","no":203,"capital_stock":"","pno_stock":"3204000328","pname_stock":"HEATER","storage_code_stock":"C03","storage_name_stock":"A","price_indicator_stock":"M","unit_stock":"EA","stock_amount_stock":"12.00","tracking_no_stock":"015","standard_stock":"SFRE","client_code_stock":"1153","client_name_stock":"bbb","priority_stock":0}]
```

I tried to remove 'boardID' and 'priority_stock' keys by this code.

```
delete returnJSON.items['boardID']
delete returnJSON.items['priority_stock']
```

or

```
delete result['boardID']
delete result['priority_stock']
```

but it failed to remove .
what's the problem?

Comment: try `delete returnJSON.items[0]['boardID']`

Comment: or try returnJSON.items.forEach(function(x){ delete x['boardID'] });

Comment: Added answer, Hope it will work as per the expectation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ES6 Array [**Map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) method with [**Arrow**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function expression.

**Working Demo**

```js
let returnJSON= {
 "items": [{
  "boardID": "9b5199799c908e48051e2e131f2d35cc",
  "no": 204,
  "capital_stock": "",
  "pno_stock": "3204000336",
  "pname_stock": "HEATER",
  "storage_code_stock": "C03",
  "storage_name_stock": "A",
  "price_indicator_stock": "M",
  "unit_stock": "EA",
  "stock_amount_stock": "12.00",
  "tracking_no_stock": "015",
  "standard_stock": "WATLOW: SFRE",
  "client_code_stock": "1193",
  "client_name_stock": "aaa",
  "priority_stock": 0
 }, {
  "boardID": "6a11d21aa400ff6c94d7d7a21b762433",
  "no": 203,
  "capital_stock": "",
  "pno_stock": "3204000328",
  "pname_stock": "HEATER",
  "storage_code_stock": "C03",
  "storage_name_stock": "A",
  "price_indicator_stock": "M",
  "unit_stock": "EA",
  "stock_amount_stock": "12.00",
  "tracking_no_stock": "015",
  "standard_stock": "SFRE",
  "client_code_stock": "1153",
  "client_name_stock": "bbb",
  "priority_stock": 0
 }]
};

var res = returnJSON.items.map(obj => {
  (obj.hasOwnProperty('boardID')) ? delete obj.boardID : '';
  (obj.hasOwnProperty('priority_stock')) ? delete obj.priority_stock : '';
  return obj;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Maybe, I need to study javascript for many years... tks very much!

Answer (score 1):

The `items` property of your `returnJSON` object is an array. You have two items, so if you want to remove, say, `boardID` and `priority_stock` from both, you'll need to loop over your items and remove each key individually, like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < returnJSON.items.length; i++) {
     delete returnJSON.items[i].boardID;
     delete returnJSON.items[i].priority_stock;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete keys for all the items

```
returnJSON.items.forEach(function(x){ delete x['boardID'] });
returnJSON.items.forEach(function(x){ delete x['priority_stock'] });
```